# local initialization

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, remix, solidity-0.8.x, solidity-0.7.x

I was working in this solidity code. here is the code sample from my project

```
interface customeInterface {
    function token0() external view returns (address);
    function token1() external view returns (address);
    function getReserves()external view returns (uint112 reserve0,uint112 reserve1,uint32 blockTimestampLast);
    function getPair(address tokenA, address tokenB)external view returns (address pair);
}

contract test {
    address public owner;
    mapping(address => uint256) balance;
    IERC20 private  token0;
    IERC20 private  token1;
    IUniswapV3Pool private  pool;

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
    function getPool()internal
    {
        //starts using the pool, token0,token1
    }
    function makePeggedPair(address tokenx, address factory) internal returns (bool result, address[] memory pair)//--optimization s needed
    {
        result = false;
        pair = new address[](2);
        address[3] memory peggeds = [
            0x55d398326f99059fF775485246999027B3197955,//usdt
            0xe9e7CEA3DedcA5984780Bafc599bD69ADd087D56,//busd
            0x8AC76a51cc950d9822D68b83fE1Ad97B32Cd580d//usdc
        ];
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
        {
            if(peggeds[i]!=tokenx)
            {
                address temp = customeInterface(factory).getPair(tokenx,peggeds[i]);
                if (temp != address(0)) {
                result = true;
                pair[0] = peggeds[i];
                pair[1] = tokenx;
                if(i==0)
                {
                    pool= IUniswapV3Pool(0xd881D9d0e0767719701305c614903F555d589586);//token 1 is usdt
                    token0 = IERC20(0x40af3827F39D0EAcBF4A168f8D4ee67c121D11c9);
                    token1 = IERC20(0x55d398326f99059fF775485246999027B3197955);
                }else if(i==1){
                     pool= IUniswapV3Pool(0x4f3126d5DE26413AbDCF6948943FB9D0847d9818);//token 1 is busd
                     token0 = IERC20(0x55d398326f99059fF775485246999027B3197955);
                     token1 = IERC20(0xe9e7CEA3DedcA5984780Bafc599bD69ADd087D56);
                }
                else if(i==2){
                     pool= IUniswapV3Pool(0x92b7807bF19b7DDdf89b706143896d05228f3121);//token 1 is usdc
                     token0 = IERC20(0x55d398326f99059fF775485246999027B3197955);
                     token1 = IERC20(0x8AC76a51cc950d9822D68b83fE1Ad97B32Cd580d);
                }
                break;
                }
            }//must finish the else to decrease path if it is vaulable token
        }

    }    

}
```

as u can see, first i decleared `token0`,`token1`,`pool` of type `IERC20`,`IERC20` `andIUniswapV3Pool` respectivly. Then i initialized them in `makePeggedPair()` function by checking some conditions.

then let's say after doing some checks, i called `getPool()`. This function uses `pool`, `token0`,`token1` by assuming they are initialized(in makePeggedPair function).

So my question is, does `getPool()` function works correctly? does those initializations last long and accessed by other functions or they are only avalibale for that block only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will work, as the variables are defined in the storage, not in the memory or calldata, once you call `makePeggedPair` it stores the instances in the storage variables `token0`, `token1`, and `pool`. They'll remain the same permanently.

Comment: ooo my god. Does those varibales(token0,token1 and pool) are storage by default . So they are the reason i am burning $1.92 for one transaction on BSC net all the time 

Comment: hello bro. If i declear them inside function, do they become non-storage type?

Comment: yes, so once you declare the variables outside the functions, it takes up the `storage` slots permanently. And when you declare them inside functions, they take up either `memory` or `calldata` which only lasts till the functions execute, after completion they are removed from the slots.